# QTP Excel ADO Query

Tags: sql, excel, ado, qtp

I am developing a test framework from scratch and datamodel (xls) file is in such a way that it has each column for each test scenario (Each Scenario has multiple steps which will be part of script).[image]
as depicted below

Now i would like to provide the option in queries so i can know which are the test cases need to run based on Execute Row with "Y" flag and then read only those particular rows from the excel which has the correspoinding parameters. E.g.
Test case: TC_001_Login has two parameters sUserName & sUserPIN. At run time i would like to query only these two fields. During the script what i know is Scenario name (TC_001_Login) and Fields (sUserName & sUserPIN).
Can anyone tell me how can i form my query to retrieve only desired results and don't use something like select * from....

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you need help regarding execution of test case depending upon status of flag "Execute_Row"?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have the field names as Column header and the Test scenarios in a Row wise, this would help you to form a key value pair for each scenarios.